# calling Interlocked after Semaphore WaitOne

Tags: c#, .net, semaphore

Came across the following code which blocks on a Semaphore when GenerateLabel is called more than 4 times concurrently. After the WaitOne a member mCurrentScanner is used to get access to a scanner. The question is if the Interlocked functions are needed after the WaitOne? I'd say no as the thread starts fresh when the WaitHandle is released, but not 100% sure.

```
  mConcurrentLabels = new Semaphore(4, 4);

  public string GenerateLabel()
  {
    mConcurrentLabels.WaitOne();

    int current = 0;

    Interlocked.Exchange(ref current, mCurrentScanner);

    (scanner, dir) = ScanMappings[current];

    Interlocked.Increment(ref mCurrentScanner);
    mCurrentScanner %= 4;
    DoLongRunningTask();
    mConcurrentLabels.Release();
  }
```

Comment: Even with the interlocked methods, this still seemingly has issues, since all you are doing accessing an array and modifying/rotating an int, I would suggest you just use a lock and be done with it

Comment: DoLongRunningTask takes like 10-20 seconds and in the meantime other calls can come in, so it's more about protecting what DoLongRunningTask does. But wasnt sure if Interlocked is absolutely needed to protect two calls to get the same index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said; The semaphore is used to limit the concurrent threads. But the body is still executed concurrently. So locks/interlocked is required.

The bigger problem is: Using `Interlocked.Exchange(ref current, mCurrentScanner);` to read the value safely and using the `Interlocked.Increment(ref mCurrentScanner);`.

It might be possible to concurrent read the same value `Exchange()` and increment it twice. So you'll select one value twice and skip the next one.

*I also advice to use try/finallies when using Semaphores.*

```
mConcurrentLabels = new Semaphore(4, 4);

public string GenerateLabel()
{
    mConcurrentLabels.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        int current = Interlocked.Increment(ref mCurrentScanner);
        
        (scanner, dir) = ScanMappings[current];
        
        // mCurrentScanner %= 4;   <------ ?
        DoLongRunningTask();
    }
    finally
    {
        mConcurrentLabels.Release();
    }
}
```

---

But if you need to mod the mCurrentScanner, I wouldn't use Interlocked.

```
mConcurrentLabels = new Semaphore(4, 4);
object mSyncRoot = new object();

public string GenerateLabel()
{
    mConcurrentLabels.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        int current;
        
        lock(mSyncRoot)
        {
            current = mCurrentScanner++;
            mCurrentScanner %= 4;
        }
        
        (scanner, dir) = ScanMappings[current];
        
        // mCurrentScanner %= 4;   <------ ?
        DoLongRunningTask();
    }
    finally
    {
        mConcurrentLabels.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, went for int current = (Interlocked.Increment(ref mCurrentScanner) - 1) % scans.Count(); it's a multithreaded service where people print stickers from an android device, now it's limited to 4 printing at same time, the 5th must wait until a sema is released

Comment: If `mCurrentScanner` is zero, `Interlocked.Increment(ref mCurrentScanner) - 1` will result in `-1` at the first call. Also doing the `% scans.Count();` will never change the `mCurrentScanner`. It will probably never flip, because of the range ;-)

Comment: that is true ye, removed the -1 to be sure

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the purpose of the semaphore is to protect the long running task and not to protect access to the private variables.
This is is useful from a resource management perspective. For example to prevent too many concurrent long running tasks from trashing a shared resource like a database.

The interlocked statements are needed to protect the private variables because the semaphore allows this code to run up to four times concurrently on different threads.

It is good practice to put the main part of this code in a `try {} finally{}` block to guarantee `mConcurrentLabels.Release()` is called exactly one time for every time `mConcurrentLabels.WaitOne()` is called.